# data not saving in custom table in database, rather it saves in template database table

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, rest

I am creating a web API with token based authentication and i have a custom model (UserModel) for my database where i want to store data when users register. instead of saving it in my custom table after sending data, it saves in a table called aspnetUsers which is the default table defined by the web API Template for saving Registered users. How can i be able to save data in my own custom database?? what do i need to do?

This is for Web API for asp.Net Web Application. i have tried to check in the DbContext and nothing seems to be working. I cant seem to figure what the problem is

```
Below is my DbContext:
    public class PeppyDbContext : IdentityDbContext<IdentityUser>
    {
    public PeppyDbContext() :base("DefaultConnection",throwIfV1Schema         :false)
    {

    }

    public static PeppyDbContext Create()
    {
        return new PeppyDbContext();
    }

    public DbSet<PeppyAPI.Models.UserModel>UserModels { get; set; }
}
```

and my Model:

public class UserModel
    {

```
    [Required][Key]
    [Display(Name = "User name")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public DateTime DateRegistered { get; set; }
}
```

I expect data to be stored in my custom table(UserModel) but it is stored in the default table(aspnetUsers) defined by asp.net web API template.

Comment: Please I haven't gotten a response yet, can anyone help

Comment: Instead of overriding asp.net identities with another table, you should put the extra data into the default identity. [https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2013/10/16/customizing-profile-information-in-asp-net-identity-in-vs-2013-templates/](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2013/10/16/customizing-profile-information-in-asp-net-identity-in-vs-2013-templates/)

Comment: thanks Jeff, just exactly what i needed